# How to insert values (Project's ID ) and show Project name for a combobox in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

Firstly, I want to apologize for the layout if it does not meet the requirement

My question is how to insert values eg.(Project's ID ) into SQL Server and show (Project name) for a combobox in WPF c#. At this moment, my program is showing ProjectName in the combobox, but have no idea to how insert it as ProjectID.

Below is XAML code:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          SelectedValuePath="ProjectID" 
          DisplayMemberPath="ProjectName" 
          x:Name="cmbProjectID"/>
```

Here is the code behind. `CMSalesMaster` is the table I'm inserting data to:

```
CMSalesMaster SaleMaster = new CMSalesMaster();
SaleMaster.SalesMasterID = Convert.ToInt32(txtSalesMasterID.Text);
SaleMaster.InvoiceNo = txtInvoiceNoW3SM.Text;
SaleMaster.ProjectID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbProjectID.Text);
SaleMaster.CompanyID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbCompanyID.Text);
SaleMaster.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbSalesID.Text);
SaleMaster.CreatorID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbCreatorID.Text);
SaleMaster.TranDate = DateTime.Now;

db.CMSalesMaster.Add(SaleMaster);
db.SaveChanges();
gvDetailSMData.ItemsSource = db.CMSalesMaster.ToList();
```

Comment: db - is the database currently using

Comment: gvDetailSMData - is the gridview showing result

Comment: thank you Craig for the edit

Answer (score -1):

Are you having trouble retrieving the ProjectID values or inserting them into the SQL DB?

Comment: Comments are a better place to ask questions. You've answered a question with a question.

Comment: My mistake. I am new and am unable to make comments yet.